# Does $\cos(U)$ have the same distribution as $\sin(U)$, when $U \in (0, 2\pi)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution

Consider an uniformly distributed variable $U$ in $(0,2\pi)$. My impression is that $\cos(U)$ have the same distribution as $\sin(U)$.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: You can see this by considering that $\cos(x) = \sin(\pi/2-x)$ and that both "wrap around" (i.e. $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$ and similarly with $\cos$).  Think about $U(0,2\pi)$ being uniform on a circle and you should be able to construct an argument that they have the same distribution easily.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, that's why I assumed they have the same distribution. Is there any standard notation for this, like $\text{dist}(\cos(U)) = \text{dist}(\sin(U))$?

Comment: Well you could write $\sin(U),\cos(U) \sim F$. There may be other notations; you could always post a terminology question.

Comment: @Glen_b Based on the upvotes I think an answer from your comments would be welcomed by future readers.

Comment: By definition, $\cos(u)$ is the x-coordinate of the point on the unit circle at angle $u$ and $\sin(u)$ is its y-coordinate.  Therefore $\cos(U)$ is the distribution of the x-coordinate of a random point on the circle and $\sin(U)$ is the distribution of the y-coordinate of a random point on that circle.  Since both the circle and the uniform distribution of its points are invariant under interchanging the coordinates, both $\cos(U)$ and $\sin(U)$ must have the same distribution.

Comment: @whuber: Is it accurate to justify it by using translation-invariance, i.e., $sin(x)=cos(x+\pi)$?

Comment: @MSIS Yes, but that requires a more extended argument, because $U+\pi$ does not have the same distribution as $U.$